# Persistent hyperlinks between notebooks in the same directory

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink, metadata

Assume that I have two notebooks, one named `A.nb`, and the other named `B.nb`, and that they are in the same directory. Then, I create a link to notebook `B.nb` in notebook `A.nb`. Next, I rename `B.nb` to `C.nb`. This breaks the link to notebook `B.nb` in the notebook `A.nb`.

**My question is**: Are there any ways to create hyperlinks between notebooks (preferably in the same directory) that persist through file name changes? Is it possible to use the notebook's metadata, for example, the unique ID number, to create the link, since this should persist through a name change? Thanks!

---

**Relevant Documentation**:

[How to Insert a Hyperlink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAHyperlink.html)

[Setting Up Hyperlinks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputAndOutputInNotebooks.html#9578)